# Out of source build fails in autotools

Tags: c, autotools, configure, automake

This might be a noobish question but I just recently started using autotools to simplify my requirements on things. Namely, I like the idea that the end user really doesn't need to go get anything to build my project on their local system.

In order to keep my source directory kind of clean I have extra configuration files saved in a `config` directory and I want to `mkdir` a build directory to keep my configuration files for the build snugly kept away. Here's my current project tree:

```
.
├── aclocal.m4
├── AUTHORS
├── autom4te.cache
│   ├── output.0
│   ├── output.1
│   ├── requests
│   ├── traces.0
│   └── traces.1
├── bin
├── build
├── Changelog
├── config
│   ├── compile
│   ├── install-sh
│   └── missing
├── config.h.in
├── configure
├── configure.ac
├── doc
├── lib
├── Makefile.am
├── Makefile.in
├── NEWS
├── README
├── README.html
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── Makefile.am
│   ├── main.c
└── test
```

**Makefile.am**

```
SUBDIRS = src
dist_doc_data = README
```

**src/Makefile.am**

```
bin_PROGRAMS = testprog
testprog_SOURCES = main.c
```

**configure.ac**

```
AC_PREREQ(2.59)

AC_INIT([testprog], [1.0], [myemail@example.com])

AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([config])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror foreign])

AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])

AC_PROG_CC

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

And finally the result of building:

```
mkdir build
cd build
../configure
make
```

**Configure output**

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for gcc... /usr/bin/clang
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether /usr/bin/clang accepts -g... yes
checking for /usr/bin/clang option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether /usr/bin/clang understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of /usr/bin/clang... none
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing depfiles commands
```

**Make output**

```
CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd .. && /bin/sh /home/me/projects/testprog/config/missing aclocal-1.15 
 cd .. && /bin/sh /home/me/projects/testprog/config/missing automake-1.15 --foreign
CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd .. && /bin/sh /home/me/projects/testprog/config/missing autoconf
/bin/sh ./config.status --recheck
running CONFIG_SHELL=/bin/sh /bin/sh ../configure CC=/usr/bin/clang --no-create --no-recursion
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for gcc... /usr/bin/clang
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether /usr/bin/clang accepts -g... yes
checking for /usr/bin/clang option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether /usr/bin/clang understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of /usr/bin/clang... none
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
 /bin/sh ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
(CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd .. && /bin/sh /home/me/projects/testprog/config/missing autoheader)
rm -f stamp-h1
touch ../config.h.in
cd . && /bin/sh ./config.status config.h
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/me/projects/testprog/build'
Making all in src
/bin/sh: line 20: cd: src: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [Makefile:352: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/me/projects/testprog/build'
make: *** [Makefile:293: all] Error 2
```

I have purchased a copy of [Autotools](https://nostarch.com/autotools.htm) as well as followed the [Automake](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Strictness) canon on gnu.org. I'm unsure where to go and neither of these sources have helped me solve it.

From what it appears it is looking for `src` inside of the `build` directory and naturally it does not exist. But every resource I look at for out of source builds doesn't seem to indicate this problem can even happen. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you invite an explanation from someone more experienced, I'll start by recapitulating my comment on your answer: you need to tell Autoconf which files the `configure` script is supposed to create, and this is the function of the `AC_CONFIG_FILES` macro.  You having failed to tell it that you wanted a `src/Makefile` was an error for both in-source and out-of-source building.

But you seem to want more explanation of what's going on under the covers, so here goes.

Your project's *source tree* is the directory tree rooted at the directory containing the top-level `configure` script.  A *build tree* is rooted at the working directory from which you run `configure`.  When a build tree differs from the source tree, you are performing an *out-of-source build*.  `configure` emits all its output into the build tree, from temporary files created by its tests to its log files to the output files designated via `AC_CONFIG_FILES` macros.  When appropriate, it also creates any subdirectories specified for output files, such as `src` for your `src/Makefile`.  It does not copy anything from the source directory *per se*, nor does it create more directories than are needed to place its output files.

The magic of out-of-source builds happens in `make`.  It relies on the "VPATH" feature of some `make` implementations, including GNU Make, by which `make` can be given a search path for prerequisites and targets of build rules.  Make always looks first for these relative to its (then) working directory, before consulting the VPATH, but in a fresh out-of-source build, the only things it can initially find there are files created by `configure`.  (As the build progresses, it may find files it previously built, too.)

But VPATH is orthogonal to recursive `make`, such as you are leveraging via Automake's `SUBDIRS` feature.  In fact, recursive `make` is not so much an explicit feature of `make` at all but rather a special case of ordinary `make` behavior (though GNU `make`, at least, recognizes it and provides a little bit of special support).  Recursive `make` operates simply by putting a `make` command into the recipe of a regular `make` rule, but **VPATH has nothing (directly) to do with the commands in recipes**.

In particular, VPATH is of no help if, say, `make` tries to recurse into a directory that does not exist in the build tree.  This is not a problem for a correct Autotools build system in which all Makefiles are generated by `configure`, because `make` will recurse only into a directories that (it expects will) have Makefiles, and `configure` will have created those directories along with the Makefiles in them.  `make`, however, knows only about the Makefile itself, not about its genesis.  If it tries to recurse into a directory that does not exist, all it knows is that a command it tried to execute failed for that reason.

That's why you got a less-than-helpful error message in your case.  But also because out-of-source building is a capability to engage after your build already works in-source.  You would have gotten a somewhat more helpful error message from an in-source build, and Automake-based Makefiles are very good about cleanup.  `make clean` and / or `make distclean` and / or `make maintainer-clean` work as advertised.

### Bonus

> Now to figure out how to make it put the binary in bin instead of src...

Why?  Seriously, what's the point, especially when you're already performing an out-of-source build?  `make` knows where to find the binaries when you're ready to install them (or to clean them up).  And, of course, the place `make` initially puts them is not intended to be their installed location.

But yes, Automake can do this.  You just need to tell it to do.  With the layout you present, the main part of that would look like this:

**src/Makefile.am**

```
bin_PROGRAMS = ../bin/testprog
___bin_testprog_SOURCES = main.c
```

You may also need to induce the top-level Makefile to ensure the `bin/` directory present before it recurses into `src/`.  If that's indeed needed, then I think you can achieve it with this variation:

**Makefile.am**

```
SUBDIRS = . src
dist_doc_data = README

all-local:
    mkdir -p bin

clean-local:
    -rm -rf bin
```

***See also***:

- [Recursive make considered harmful](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf)
- [Autotools Mythbuster: non-recursive Automake](https://autotools.io/automake/nonrecursive.html)

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution to this particular problem but I don't want to award myself any points because I would like someone more experienced to come and explain it better.

The solution is rather obscure:

```
AC_PREREQ(2.59)

AC_INIT([testprog], [1.0], [myemail@example.com])

AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([config])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror foreign])

AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])

AC_PROG_CC

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile src/Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

The `src/Makefile` was missing from `AC_CONFIG_FILES`. With this it builds, and in the build directory creates a `src` directory that contains the binary. Now to figure out how to make it put the binary in `bin` instead of `src`...

Comment: Note that this omission presented a problem for in-source building, too.  The error message would have been different, and the problem could have been masked by the presence of a pre-existing `src/Makefile`, but it's an error all the same.  It's not so obscure that you need to tell Autoconf which files it is supposed to create.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thank you for your reply. What I think I mean by obscure is the absolutely terrible (bordering on useless) error message from make that didn't help me debug this. I should have been clearer.